# Document structure of a value for arbitrary keys in an Object in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I have a function `factory`:

```js
function factory(events) {
  for(const key in events) {
    const { before, after } = events[key]
  }
}
```

Where the argument `events` is typically:

```js
{
  only: {
    before(){}
    after(){}
  },
  except: {
    before(){}
    after(){}
  },
}
```

Where the keys `only`, `except` can be anything but the values are always (must be) of type `{before, after}` where both `before`, `after` are functions.

How do I document this structure for `events` argument in my `factory` function using JSDoc?

The only solution I can think of is to make `events` an array, then I can use `typedef` like this:

```js
/**
 * @typedef event
 * @property {function} before
 * @property {function} after
 */
/**
 * @typedef eventTuple
 * @property {string} key
 * @property {event} event
 */
/**
 * @param {[eventTuple]} events
 */
function factory(events) {
  for(const { key, event } of events) {
    const { before, after } = event
  }
}
```

But I really wanna keep the original structure.

Is it possible to document this `event` type definition in my original structure?

I'm mainly concerned about it working in VSCode which lifts these type definitions from JSDoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can use TS syntax.

p.s. honestly, I'm not sure if this works everywhere. But it works for intellisense at least

```js
/**
 * @typedef event
 * @property {function} before
 * @property {function} after
 */

/**
 * @param {{[key: string]: event}} events
 */
function factory(events) {
    for (const key in events) {
        const { before, after } = events[key]
    }
}
```